# Format python PATCH request from curl command

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have a curl command I can run from my local machine that works, but transferring it to a python script is giving me difficulties. Here's the curl command that works:

curl -X PATCH "http://localhost:9999/pins/1" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"state": "on"}"

And here is what I have so far as a python request:

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:9999/pins/1'
payload = {'state':'on'}
head = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}

r = requests.patch(url, payload, headers=head)
```

But I am receiving a 400 response. Any direction?

Also, if I format it as

```
r = requests.patch(url, data=payload)
```

I get a 500 response code. Also should be noted: I can run a simple get request easily by running something like

```
r = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: change this `r = requests.patch(url, data=payload)` to `r = requests.patch(url, json=payload)`

Comment: ^ This worked, thank you so much!

Comment: I have posted an answer so that anyone who lands up will look at the answer than the comments

Answer (score 3):

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:9999/pins/1'
payload = {'state':'on'}
head = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}

r = requests.patch(url, json=payload)
```

change this `r = requests.patch(url, data=payload)` to `r = requests.patch(url, json=payload)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to make sure that your payload is valid json.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://localhost:9999/pins/1'
payload = {'state':'on'}
head = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}

r = requests.patch(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=head)
```